# _validateTextureView:557: failed assertion `Texture View Validation cannot create View from Memoryless texture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Run Simulator in Xcode 13 beta, I came across the crash，What should I do about it ？

```
_validateTextureView:557: failed assertion `Texture View Validation
cannot create View from Memoryless texture.
texture usage (0x04) doesn't specify MTLTextureUsagePixelFormatView (0x10)
'
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Users/****/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Truckloads-cpaazflnngvcgdegppomicvsczis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Users/****/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/****/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Users/****/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Users/****/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Truckloads-cpaazflnngvcgdegppomicvsczis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
_validateTextureView:557: failed assertion `Texture View Validation
cannot create View from Memoryless texture.
texture usage (0x04) doesn't specify MTLTextureUsagePixelFormatView (0x10)
'
CoreSimulator 772.1 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (84610676-549B-47F6-A87E-D0B4877032ED) - Runtime: iOS 15.0 (19A5261u) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
(lldb)
```

Comment: Hello, facing a similar issue, did you find a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: Same issue... is there a bug report about this somewhere?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.

> You should be able to work around it by turning off Metal Validation in Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Metal API Validation

From Apple: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683832